# Better way than nested for loops to generate all positive slices

Tags: python

I want to generate all the sequential positive slices of a list in python.

Is there a neater way of doing it than a nested for loop? I'm stuck for what to search for.

So for a list of length 3 I'd want the following slices:

```
input_list[0:1]
input_list[0:2]
input_list[0:3]
input_list[1:2]
input_list[1:3]
input_list[2:3]
```

This is the nested for loop way of getting what I want:

```
input_list = ["stuff", "and", "things"]
output_list = []
for start_index in range(0, len(input_list)):
    for end_index in range(1, len(input_list)+1):
        if start_index < end_index:
            output_list.append(input_list[start_index:end_index])
print(output_list)
# OUTPUT:
>>> [['stuff'], ['stuff', 'and'], ['stuff', 'and', 'things'], ['and'], ['and', 'things'], ['things']]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can generate all index pairs for a list `xs` as follows:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> xs = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> pairs = combinations(range(len(xs) + 1), 2)
>>> list(pairs)
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Now simply make a slice for each pair:

```
>>> result = [xs[i:j] for i, j in pairs]
>>> result
[['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']]
```